# When can we say that the null space of $A$= The basis of the eigenspace at a certain $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
-2 &  2 & -3 \\
 2 &  1 & -6 \\ 
-1 & -2 &  0   
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After we solve this we will find $\lambda_1=5$, $\lambda_2=-3$, $\lambda_3=-3$ and then we get the eigenvector at $\lambda=-3$, and it will be
$$ 
x = \alpha \begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} 
+ \beta\begin{bmatrix} 3\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which will be equal to the basis of the null space if we solve for $(A+3I)x=0$ is, this always true or is this just a special case?

Comment: But if we solve $Ax=0$ we don’t obtain $(-2,1,0)$ nor $(3,0,1)$ :/

Comment: @azif00 you won't exactly get the same  vector it depends on the assumption of your free variables, you should get a linearly dependent one

Comment: It's the null space of $(A+3I)$, if you did all the calculations right.

Comment: The eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ is the same thing as the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$. So it will *always* be the case that the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$ are precisely the (nonzero) solutions to $(A-\lambda I)=0$. That is not a "special case".

Comment: There is one vector that you claim is an eigenvector corresponding to $-3$ which is not an eigenvector: the one you get with $\alpha=\beta=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\lambda$-eigenspace is by definition the subspace consisting of all eigenvectors of the given eigenvalue $\lambda$, together with the zero vector. Any basis of this eigenspace will consist of eigenvector(s), i.e. the null space of $(A + 3I)$.

In your example with $\lambda=-3$, the null space happens to be $2$-dimensional, so any two linearly independent vectors will form a basis of that subspace and will be eigenvectors of eigenvalue $3$.

Remember that although eigenvalues are "rigid"—they have particular values—their corresponding eigenvectors are only defined up to scaling and linear combination. Specifically, given any two linearly independent eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ of eigenvalue $\lambda=3$,
$$
\mathbf{x} = \alpha\mathbf{v} + \beta\mathbf{w}
$$
is *also* an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda=3$, provided that $(\alpha, \beta) \neq (0, 0)$ to make sure that $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$.